# How to verify the button is clicked or not?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, protractor

I have 2 sorting buttons in the page, they are **Recent** and **Name**, when I open the page, we could see the **Name** button is clicked initially, the **Recent** button is not.
I would write a e2e test by protractor to verify that the **Recent** button is not click when i just open the page.

The html elements below:

```html
<button ng-click="setFilter('-dateorder')" class="col-xs-6 btn btn-default" ng-class="{active:isSelected('-dateorder')}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Sort by Recent" tabindex="0">Recent</button>
<button ng-click="setFilter('name')" class="col-xs-6 btn btn-default active" ng-class="{active:isSelected('name')}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Sort by Name" tabindex="0">Name</button>
```

What I was done is below, but seems incorrect, becuase the **nameclick1.isEnabled()** is always return **ture**, even though I change to **Name** button

```html
it('Verify the sort button click or not', function() {
    var nameclick1=element(by.buttonText('Recent'));
 expect(nameclick1.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
    //expect(nameclick1.getAttribute('enabled')).toBe(false);
  });
```

Can anyone helps here?

Comment: What I need is to return a false, because the **Recent** button is really not been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expect(element(by.css('button:not(.active)[data-original-title*=Recent]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

A "Recent" element without "active" class is present.

Answer (score 0):

Check that button contains the "active" class or not.